# Merging all txt files in multiple folders or bringing all of the files into one single folder

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

So i have one master folder with 2 sub folders , each sub folder contains 20 folders , All the 20 folders have 3 more sub folders. Each of these 3 folders have 4 to 5 text Files of 5 to 10 mb each.

I want to merge all these txt files into one single file and also bring all these files into one single folders eliminating all the sub folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move all files (for example, .txt) of a tree to a single folder, use the following command:

for /r "sourcedir" %F in (*.txt) do move "%F" "targetdir"

Substitute the appropriate source and target directory paths instead of sourcedir and targetdir.

To merge all .txt files into a single file:

copy *.txt target.txt

For binary files, add the /b option before source file template.